# Inserting additional data without changing the old data in a column

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

I have a table in which users can store the data, the following is the code

```
 public function upload($name,$id)
{
    $this->db->set('document',$name);
    $this->db->where('id',$id);
    $this->db->update('employee_details');
    return true;
}
```

it works fine, but after this update, when I try to add additional data(here file) the old data got erased, and only the last uploaded data is there, how can I add the data without erase the old data?

Comment: What old data is getting erased? The data for the specified ID? That's sort of what an update function does...

Comment: Actually I just need to concat the new data with old data

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question.

Comment: not exactly, but i don't know how to do it

Comment: You don't now how concatenate in codeigniter?

Comment: I got it now, thanks all